# Get user input without assuming there is a question

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just want to get the value that the user types in

I want something similar to C#'s `Console.ReadLine()` or Java's `bufferedReader.readLine()`

There are many examples of how to get the user input using nodejs, but all of those that I have found, assume that there is a question.

For example:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});


rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
   ...
}
```

Instead, I want something like `r1.readLine()` without the `r1.question()`

It looks like there is a lot of examples out there, but honestly, more than half of them seem like people just copy and paste from each other.

Comment: Use an empty string for the question?

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, that would work ofc, but I think that's a hack, and was hoping the was a more "correct" way of doing it, to have cleaner and prettiere code. But if there isn't, then this will ofc be my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use an empty string for `rl.question`, you could simply listen on the `line` event as you don't even have to prompt the user with a question at all:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    console.log(`You typed ${line}`);
});
```

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line):

> The 'line' event is emitted whenever the input stream receives an
> end-of-line input (\n, \r, or \r\n). This usually occurs when the user
> presses Enter or Return.
>
> The listener function is called with a string containing the single
> line of received input.